# Issue extending class - override private members

Tags: scala

I am doing a simple scala application of extending a class.
 I am getting a error which i am not understanding i.e. Error is "private  [this] val xc:Int"  at Location class.

Please find code below.

```
class Point(xc:Int ,yc:Int) {
    var x:Int =xc;
var y:Int =yc;

def move(dx:Int ,dy:Int)
{
    x=x+dx;
    y=y+dy;
    println("Point x location for Point Class = "+x)
    println("Point y location for Point Class = "+y)  
}
}

class Location(override val xc: Int, override val yc: Int,
   val zc :Int) extends Point(xc, yc){
   var z: Int = zc

   def move(dx: Int, dy: Int, dz: Int) {
      x = x + dx
      y = y + dy
      z = z + dz
      println ("Point x location : " + x);
      println ("Point y location : " + y);
      println ("Point z location : " + z);
   }
}
object Runner
{
    def main(arg : Array[String])
    {
//val pt = new Point(4,5);
//pt.move(4, 5)

val lo = new Location(1,2,3);
lo.move(1, 2,3)
    }
}
```

Comment: use `class Point(val xc:Int ,val yc:Int)` instead of `class Point(xc:Int ,yc:Int)`

Comment: Removed `override` statements on Scala 2.11 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Might be because a problem overriding private/protected members in scala

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1994

you can fix this by declaring class Point this way :

```
class Point(val xc:Int , val yc:Int)
```

*when you dont write val in the param's they are private members

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
class Point(var x: Int, var y: Int) {
  def move(dx: Int, dy: Int) = {
    x=x+dx
    y=y+dy
  }
}

class Location(
  x: Int,
  y: Int,
  var z :Int) extends Point(x, y) {

  def move(dx: Int, dy: Int, dz: Int) = {
    super.move(dx, dy)
    z = z + dz
  }
}

object Runner {
  def main(arg : Array[String]) = {
    val pt = new Point(4,5)
    pt.move(4, 5)

    val lo = new Location(1,2,3)
    lo.move(1, 2,3)
  }
}
```